# mingw32-make.exe: *** No rule to make target 'project'. Stop

Tags: c, mingw, clion

I am trying to compile a basic code using Clion and MinGW.

This is my CmakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES CheckParenthesis.c)
add_executable(project${SOURCE_FILES})
```

and the error I get is:

> mingw32-make.exe: *** No rule to make target 'project'.  Stop.

Please advise.

Comment: Which commands are you invoking?

Comment: I am pretty newbie. I am not sure what you ask. I believe you refer to the command line that should look like this: gcc CheckParenthesis.c -o but i am not sure where to plug that in the Clion platform

Comment: You are running some command in the console to get this error, aren't you?

Comment: In general, your CMakeLists.txt should work, although it contains some defects. Please edit your question the CMakeLists.txt is properly formatted and look exactly like in your project (indent it with 4 spaces) You're missing spaces and line breaks now. Also please check that everything is fine at `Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolchains` in CLion.

Comment: Ah.. it's an IDE..